# weird thing happens when window is scaled down

Tags: html, css

Practicing for responsive web, in the following code, in the `.container1` div, I have inserted a background image of width:800 height:698 px. I have also set the dimensions of the `.container1` div accordingly. However whenever I try to scale down the window, there is a huge vertical gap that comes between the conatiner1 (blue) and container2 div (red). It looks like whenever the window is scaled down, the container2 div moves down hence leaving a blue (container1 div's background color) gap between the two div's. I dont know why this happens? Specially when I have set the dimensions of container1 div exactly the same as the image size.

```css
html, body {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.container1 {
    height: 698px;
    max-width: 800px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,204,1);
    /* [disabled]float: left; */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-image: url(http://i1062.photobucket.com/albums/t482/gautam_official/VAIBHAV%20CINE%20MULTIPLEX%20VAISHALI%20NAGAR_zpsl0tdrevr.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container2 {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">

</div>
<div class="container2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason of this is :

```
background-size: contain;
```

Background image must be contained inside div.

> Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area

try to use

```
 background-size: cover;
```

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

or if you want cover whole div but without keep proportions use:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

> Sets the width and height of the background image in percent of the parent element. The first value sets the width, the second value sets the height. If only one value is given, the second is set to "auto"

```css
    html, body {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-left: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width: 100%;
    }

    .container1 {
     height: 698px;
     max-width: 800px;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,204,1);
     /* [disabled]float: left; */
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     background-image: url(http://i1062.photobucket.com/albums/t482/gautam_official/VAIBHAV%20CINE%20MULTIPLEX%20VAISHALI%20NAGAR_zpsl0tdrevr.jpg);
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     position: relative;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .container2 {
     background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
     height: 250px;
     width: 500px;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     position: relative;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     margin-top: 0px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container1">

    </div>
    <div class="container2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
    dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
    libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
    dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
    libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
    </div>
```

Comment: I used `background-size: contain;` because i wanted the image to scale down proportionally whenever the window is scaled down.